Informix DB " -556 Cannot create, drop or modify an object that is external to the current database "
I have created a simple procedure in Informix
Database.
I am able to run this procedure from Data Studio (Informix Development Tool) and the procedure is executed successfully.
But, when i try to execute the same procedure from "SYSADMIN --> ph_task" or "Open Admin Tool"
I am getting an error " -556 Cannot create, drop or modify an object that is external to the current database ".
Here i have mentioned only test code.
If a get the solution then i will use it accordingly in my original code.
Sample Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE neura_practice_dev.proc_test()
create table neura_practice_dev@inst_13:proc_test_tbl(id smallint);
END PROCEDURE;

This question is about programming and software development.

If the current database is neura_practice_dev@inst_13, the procedure will probably execute without the error.  If the current database is any other database, you can expect that error.  I don't have access to Data Studio, but I'd suspect that it has neura_practice_dev@inst_13 as the current database when you execute the procedure — and OAT and ph_task do not (it's likely to be the sysmaster database that's current).
